# JQuery Ajax not replacing div element with text file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

So, I'm quite new to JQuery, and AJAX in general. I've made an app to retrieve data from Spotify's API, which writes to song.txt (This part works just fine. It updates every second, as it should.) and the HTML file will pull the contents of song.txt and change the div with id of 'track'

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Camashima's Site</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function () {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#track').load('../output/song.txt');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Currently Playing:
        <div id="track">
            .
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS code posts the html file to the server just fine, and I see Currently playing: but nothing else. So that tells me it's not the issue. So, what am I doing wrong here? It should be loading song.txt into the "track" div, right?

Also, I'm using Goorm-ide to host my container, and the console isn't as in-depth as chrome's dev tools.
**Expected**: "track" div to be replaced with song.txt contents

**Result**: Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you add some information about what the song.txt looks like? Have you tried console.log song.txt?

Comment: Use Google Chrome and go to the console and report any errors.  Check the 'network' tab in dev tools and see if the request is made for the text file.  If it is, does it load or is there an error?  What are the urls for your page and the text file?  This looks like a home page that goes in '/', and you are using '..' in the url to access the file.   My guess is that the file is not being served.

Comment: @NicklasF The song.txt is literally just the output of fs.writeFileSync('./output/song.txt', text). With the server.js frozen, the song.txt contains the following: 2:47 / 2:52 - Falling (feat. blackbear) - blackbear Remix by Trevor Daniel

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I can't debug it, chrome developer tools are disabled on this laptop, for some reason, hence why I'm using goorm. Here's the link to the served html. https://camashimas-current-track.run-eu-central1.goorm.io/

Comment: That looks like your html is in the root folder being served.  The problem is that song.txt is not in the directory being served.  The load() call happens on the client and the url needs to resolve to something that can also be served by the same server.  There is no way for your browser to use '..' to go to the parent directory, since there is none being served.  If your url was something like 'https://example.com/mypage/index.html' then it would try to fetch 'https://example.com/output/song.txt'.  Since there is no path element to go up to, there is no way to get a url.

Comment: I'm using express and path to use and get the directories, although the issue was two periods before /output. Goorm handles differently, and it only needed one, as soon as I changed it to "./output/song.txt", it started updating, along with adding the answer David provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not the AJAX part works, the main problem here is that you're (1) adding tons of `document.ready` events and (2) doing so indefinitely in *very rapid succession*.

You can correct this by (1) using *one* `document.ready` event and setting your interval within that and (2) providing a *delay* to the interval, even if it's just one second.  For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // execute this code once, and only once, when the document is ready
  setInterval(function () {
    $('#track').load('../output/song.txt');
  }, 1000);  // perform this interval operation every 1000 ms
});
```

From there, you can then begin to reasonably debug the AJAX issue (if there even is one).  I realize [in a comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701421/jquery-ajax-not-replacing-div-element-with-text-file#comment124988650_70701421) you indicated that Chrome developer tools are disabled.  So you'll either need to correct that or find another tool to use to debug it.  But you're essentially going to want to observe the AJAX requests and responses.  Confirm that the address being requested is what you expect it to be, and observe the response from the server.  The client-side code here is extremely simple and "works" just fine, but if the overall result isn't what's expected then your only recourse is to debug those interactions with the server.